# Select Disabled=Disabled not working on samsung galaxy tablet

Tags: asp.net, galaxy-tab

On a galaxy tablet android version 4.1.1, place the following on a web page (which is rendered from dropdownlist with enabled = false to prevent user selection), and open using the tablet's default browser (I am in .NET 3.0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    THIS TEXT SHOULD NOT BE GRAY (AND IT IS NOT)
    <br />
    THIS DROPDOWN SHOULD BE DISABLED (not selectable/gray) (AND IT IS):
    <select id="testSelect" disabled="disabled">
        <option selected="selected" value="0"></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">1</option>
    </select>
    THIS TEXT SHOULD NOT BE GRAY (BUT IT IS ON A GALAXY TAB)
</body>
</html>
```

All subsequent controls on the page after the select control are rendered in the 'gray' disabled style. The dropdown list is gray as expected, but so too is all HTML on the remainder of the page (on a tablet only; works fine on LG android, iphone, etc). 
1. Why?
2. How to resolve, preferably in one place for the entire application such as a skin/css fix (or by fixing asp:DropDownList)

Comment: Ummm...my guess would be because you have `disabled="disabled"`. Remove that and it shouldn't be grey anymore.

Comment: disabled="disabled is coming from .NET .Enabled = false which is used hundreds of times throughout the application.  Is that no longer supported for dropdownlist?  If I remove disabled=disabled, the dropdownlist would be enabled, and the intention is to disable it (but not disable the remainder of the page, which occurs on the tablet only).

Comment: Interesting. Do you mind to post the HTML full codes?

Comment: Sounds like the html isn't valid.

Comment: Which browser are u using on Galaxy? I don't have a tablet but Chrome for Samsung Galaxy S4 phone displays this http://jsfiddle.net/xos9L26k/ as designed - the text below is not disabled

Comment: I do not think it is Chrome.  It is the default browser 'Internet' that ships with it.  Our users do not have the know how to switch to chrome so I would like to stick with it.